# How to create a dataframe by appending heterogenous column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a `dataframe` like 2 columns and several rows

```
[
 ['text1',[float1, float2, float3]]
 ['text2',[float4, float5, float6]]
 .
 .
 .
]
```

The names of the columns should be `content` and `embeddings`. `text1`, `text2` are for `content` column, the list of floats is in `embeddings` column.

The code I have written is

```
mycontent = ["i live in space","i live my life to fullest", "dogs live in kennel","we live to eat and not eat to live","cricket lives in heart of every indian","live and let live","my house is in someplace","my office is in someotherplace","chair is red"]

contents_and_embeddings_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['content','embeddings'])

for content in mycontent:
    embedding = get_embedding(content,engine='textsearchcuriedoc001mc') #returns list of floats
    contents_and_embeddings_df.append(pd.DataFrame([content,embedding]))
   

contents_and_embeddings_df
```

In output I get several warnings of  `contents_and_embeddings_df.append(pd.DataFrame([content,embedding])) /tmp/ipykernel_15879/3971327095.py:8: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead. contents_and_embeddings_df.append(pd.DataFrame([content,embedding]))`

The content of the dataframe is empty. I see only two headers - `content    embeddings`

I tried few other ways as well but am not able to create the desired `dataframe`

```
for content in mycontent:
    embedding = get_embedding(content,engine='textsearchcuriedoc001mc')
    #pd.concat(contents_and_embeddings_df,pd.DataFrame([content,embedding])) --> doesn't work
#contents_and_embeddings_df.append(pd.DataFrame([content,embedding])) --> doesn't work
    tempdf = pd.DataFrame([content,embedding]) #doesn't work.
#    tempdf = pd.DataFrame([content,embedding], columns=['content','embeddings']) --> doesn't compile
    contents_and_embeddings_df.add(tempdf) # doesn't work. 
 

contents_and_embeddings_df #shows empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply generate your dataframe data with a list comprehension:

```py
data = [(content, get_embedding(content,engine='textsearchcuriedoc001mc')) for content in mycontent]
contents_and_embeddings_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['content','embeddings'])
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you know why `tempdf = pd.DataFrame([content,embedding], columns=['content','embeddings'])` doesn't compile and `tempdf = pd.DataFrame([content,embedding]); contents_and_embeddings_df.add(tempdf)` didn't work?

Comment: @ManuChadha the way pandas interprets data when you write `[content, embedding]` is that each element in the list is a row, not a column, so the number of columns in the data won't match what you specified with `columns=['content','embeddings']`. `df.add` attempts to sum `df` with `tempdf`; what you would actually want is `concat` in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.append` is deprecated. It's an inefficient method since it allocates new memory to store the resultant dataframe. It has been removed in pandas 2.0.

It's better to construct these two columns individually before assembling them into a dataframe:

```py
embeddings = [get_embedding(content, engine="textsearchcuriedoc001mc") for content in mycontent]
contents_and_embeddings_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "content": mycontent,
    "embeddings": embeddings
})
```